# overlapping elements in css without using grid

Tags: html, css

how to create this kind of effect(see image from snippet) in CSS without using grid. i'm thinking if i can achieve the same effect using positioning or something else.
thanks in advance!

```html
<html>

<body>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDNov.png" style="width:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you even use css grid? This can bw acheived simply using :after, z-index and position absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="https://blog.prezi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/joshua-earle-157231-unsplash-1024x683.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```